# Why are my discord buttons disabling until I press a button?

Tags: python, button, discord.py

In my discord, file-based connect 4 game, I'm creating a way for your game to be to reshown by calling the original function. It unsends your first game and works perfectly fine, but it doesn't carry over which buttons are disabled. A button becomes disabled if the top item of its column is full, meaning that when they aren't disabled, you are able to place them in full rows. Once I press a button, it seems to update the other buttons. Is there a way to possibly update the view they are in, or something along those lines?

```
  open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
  board = []
  IDS = open_file.readline()
  piece = open_file.readline()
  for _ in range(6):
    value = open_file.readline()
    board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
# board is a 2d array made up of each played piece, being 6 lists, each list having 7 values
  open_file.close()
# where I'm trying to disable the buttons
  buttons = [button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7]
  for items in range(7):
    print(board[0][items])
    if board[0][items] == ":green_circle:" or board[0][items] == ":red_circle:":
      print(',,')
      buttons[items].disabled = True
```

Comment: Even when I check if the button is disabled, it returns true. So it has the property of disabled, but its not being truly disabled

Comment: This is way too much code. Please post a [mre] with just the code related to the problem.

Comment: Yeah. Though so. Removed most of the basic stuff

Answer (score 1):

Found Out my Fix. I moved my code which disables the buttons above their addition to view, meaning that their disabled property was now passed onto the discord message

```
  button1 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="1️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=0)
  button2 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="2️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=0)
  button3 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="3️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=0)
  button4 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="4️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button5 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="5️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button6 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="6️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button7 = Button(label="",
                   emoji="7️⃣",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=1)
  button8 = Button(label="End Game",
                   style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray,
                   row=2)
# Placed the check here, before adding buttons to view
   open_file = open(ctx.author.name + "#", "r")
  first = open_file.readline()
  message = ""
  if not first == ":green_circle:\n":
    IDS = open_file.readline()
  board = []
  for _ in range(6):
    value = open_file.readline()
    board.append(value.strip("\n").split(","))
  open_file.close()
  buttons = [button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7]
  for items in range(7):
    if board[0][items] == ":green_circle:" or board[0][items] == ":red_circle:":
      buttons[items].disabled = True
      
  

  
  
  view1 = View()
  view1.add_item(button1)
  view1.add_item(button2)
  view1.add_item(button3)
  view1.add_item(button4)
  view1.add_item(button5)
  view1.add_item(button6)
  view1.add_item(button7)
  view1.add_item(button8)

  m = await ctx.send(piece + " turn\n" + L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3 + "\n" +
                     L4 + "\n" + L5 + "\n" + L6,
                     view=view1)
# check used to be below, meaning that its attributes wouldn't be added to view1 when sent
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the fixed code.

Comment: Just did. Found out that by simpling placing the disabling check before my declaration of view, I was able to have the buttons have the correct states